# How to sniff packets on cloud (in AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, tracking, p2p, packet-sniffers

I want to track the packets routed between various peers and a master on AWS. Can someone suggest a method/tool to do the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to track the packets on the instances themselves, or in between them?

Answer (score 1):

Sniffing between instances:

[Is sniffing subnet traffic supported?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=35683)

[Amazon Web Services: Overview of Security Processes](http://www.utdallas.edu/~muratk/courses/cloud11f_files/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf)

> Packet sniffing by other tenants
>   It is not possible for a virtual instance running in promiscuous mode to receive or “sniff” traffic that is intended for a
>   different virtual instance. While customers can place their interfaces into promiscuous mode, the hypervisor will not
>   deliver any traffic to them that is not addressed to them. Even two virtual instances that are owned by the same
>   customer located on the same physical host cannot listen to each other’s traffic. Attacks such as ARP cache poisoning do
>   not work within Amazon EC2 and Amazon VPC. While Amazon EC2 does provide ample protection against one customer
>   inadvertently or maliciously attempting to view another’s data, as a standard practice customers should encrypt
>   sensitive traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [VPC Traffic Mirroring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/what-is-traffic-mirroring.html). This provides the ability to send traffic to two places: the intended destination, plus another endpoint for logging and/or analysis.

[This AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-vpc-traffic-mirroring-to-monitor-and-secure-your-aws-infrastructure/) discusses four use cases:

- Network security
- Network performance monitoring
- Customer experience management
- Network troubleshooting